# Can't remove an object from a list

Tags: java, android, list

i have a gridview, when an item is clicked. it will iterate through a list and it should remove an object from the list when it matches a string. here's my code so far but it doesn't work. i don't know what is wrong. pls help.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
    {
         String sel_id = list2.get(arg2).stud_id.toString();

         for(int i=0; i<late_list.size(); i++)
         {
             if(late_list.get(i).stud_id.toString() == sel_id.toString())
             {
                 late_list.remove(i);
             }
         }
     }

});
```

Comment: String is an object.  `==` tests for two objects being the same instance.  As jlordo says (please accept his answer), use .equals() to test the string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't compare String with `==`, use `equals()`

`==` checks if the operands reference the same object instance (only checks the same value for primitive types)

`equals()` checks for same object contents (for classes that override the `equals` method, and `String` certainly does).

Consequently your `if` condition must be

```
if (late_list.get(i).stud_id.toString().equals(sel_id))
```

Also, there is no need to call `toString()` on a `String` object, as you did on `sel_id`

If your `stud_id` is a `String` also, you can write

```
if (late_list.get(i).stud_id.equals(sel_id))
```